# Printing PDF to PageSize using command by invoking Windows Process - C#

Tags: c#, windows, printing, process, pdf-generation

I am trying to Print PDF file using shell commands of Windows Process like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "print",
    Arguments = String.Format("/h /t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", "MyFile.pdf", "My Printer Name")
};
p.Start();
```

I needs to change the page size (A4 to Envelope C5) of my default printer. I am wondering a way I can pass a command to change page size of printer. Using this Process `Arguments`:

```
Arguments = String.Format("/h /t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", "MyFile.pdf", "My Printer Name")
```

Is there any command that I can pass to this arguments like `/PageSize "Envalope C5"` ?

PS: Above process code triggers my Adobe Acrobat Reader DC to print the PDF file.

Comment: @KJ so there is no way to change printer settings programmatically ? Hmmm, I will try your suggestion for duplicating printer for now. Thanks!